# Cummulative Sum with Reset Value

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

Consider the following table:

```
ID | GROUP_ID | ORDER_VAL | RESET_VAL | VAL 
---+----------+-----------+-----------+-----
1  | 1        | 1         | (null)    | 3   
2  | 1        | 2         | (null)    | 2   
3  | 1        | 3         | (null)    | 1   
4  | 1        | 4         | 4         | 2   
5  | 1        | 5         | (null)    | 1   
6  | 2        | 1         | (null)    | 4   
7  | 2        | 2         | 2         | 3   
8  | 2        | 3         | (null)    | 4   
9  | 2        | 4         | (null)    | 2   
10 | 2        | 5         | (null)    | 2   
11 | 2        | 6         | (null)    | 4   
12 | 2        | 7         | 14        | 2   
13 | 2        | 8         | (null)    | 2
```

For each row, I need to compute the cumulative sum of `VAL` for all previous rows (ordered by `ORDER_VAL` and grouped by `GROUP_ID`), but each time a non-`NULL` `RESET_VAL` is encountered, I need to use that value for the sum. The rows that follow also need to build on top of the `RESET_VAL` instead of using the actual sum. Note that each group can have multiple reset values.

This is the result I expect for the above table:

```
ID | GROUP_ID | ORDER_VAL | RESET_VAL | VAL | CUMSUM
---+----------+-----------+-----------+-----+-------
1  | 1        | 1         | (null)    | 3   | 0
2  | 1        | 2         | (null)    | 2   | 3
3  | 1        | 3         | (null)    | 1   | 5
4  | 1        | 4         | 4         | 2   | 4
5  | 1        | 5         | (null)    | 1   | 6
6  | 2        | 1         | (null)    | 4   | 0
7  | 2        | 2         | 2         | 3   | 2
8  | 2        | 3         | (null)    | 4   | 5
9  | 2        | 4         | (null)    | 2   | 9
10 | 2        | 5         | (null)    | 2   | 11
11 | 2        | 6         | (null)    | 4   | 13
12 | 2        | 7         | 14        | 2   | 14
13 | 2        | 8         | (null)    | 2   | 16
```

If not for the reset values, I could use a window query:

```
SELECT temp.*,
       COALESCE(SUM(val) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY order_val ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),
                0) AS cumsum
FROM temp;
```

[SQLFiddle of the above](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3558b9/2/0)

I was originally mistakenly thinking that I could just put `RESET_VAL` at the beginning of the `COALESCE`, but this won't work since it won't reset the value for following rows.

I also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20349811/1394393), but it only resets back to zero, not to a value in the column. Adapting it to do so is proving non-trivial because that value must propagate to all following rows.

A recursive query seems like a natural fit, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do that as of yet.

I should probably mention that the table I actually have to deal with is much larger (hundreds of thousands to a couple million rows) than the example above, so please mention if there are any performance pitfalls with any answer.

Comment: @ypercube Because I make lots of silly mistakes every day, especially when doing things manually. =) Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: @Colin'tHart Sorry, I'm confused by your question. When a non-`NULL` `reset_val` is encountered, it should completely replace the cumulative sum. It can be any value, anywhere in the group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works but there's probably some more clever version. Explanation of the query's logic:

We first find how many "resets" have been done up to and including the current row by counting the not nulls of the `reset_val` column, so we can separate the rows into subgroups.

We also use another window function `LAST_VALUE()` with `IGNORE NULLS`, so we can find the last `reset_value`.

Note that both these window functions `COUNT()` and `LAST_VALUE()` have an `ORDER BY`, therefore the default window `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`. Omitted in the query, to make the code more clear.

Assuming that the `val` is not nullable, the other window function could also be shortened, from:

```
       COALESCE(SUM(val) OVER 
         (PARTITION BY group_id, reset_count 
          ORDER BY order_val 
          ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                   AND 1 PRECEDING), 0)
```

(avoiding the `COALESCE()` as well) to:

```
       SUM(val) OVER 
         (PARTITION BY group_id, reset_count 
          ORDER BY order_val)
       - val
```

Finally, in the second cte, we use the above found subgroups (using `PARTITION BY group_id, reset_count`) to find the cumulative sums.

```
WITH x AS
  ( SELECT temp.*, 
           COUNT(reset_val) OVER 
               (PARTITION BY group_id 
                ORDER BY order_val)
             AS reset_count,
           COALESCE(LAST_VALUE(reset_val IGNORE NULLS) OVER 
               (PARTITION BY group_id 
                ORDER BY order_val), 0)
             AS reset_value
    FROM temp
  ) ,
y AS 
  ( SELECT x.*,
           COALESCE(SUM(val) OVER 
             (PARTITION BY group_id, reset_count 
              ORDER BY order_val 
              ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                       AND 1 PRECEDING), 0)            
           + reset_value AS cumsum      
    FROM x
  )
SELECT *
FROM y ;
```

Test at [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fe988/11).

---

Another variation, based on [@Chris' recursive answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104596/cummulative-sum-with-reset-value/104609#104609). (slightly improved, works with non-consecutive `order_val`, avoids the final `GROUP BY`).
Also works in case the first row of a group has a `reset_val`:

```
WITH row_nums AS
  ( SELECT id, group_id, order_val, reset_val, val, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group_id
                              ORDER BY order_val)
             AS rn
    FROM temp
  ) ,
updated_temp (id, group_id, order_val, reset_val, val, rn, cumsum) AS
  ( SELECT id, group_id, order_val, reset_val, val, rn, 
           COALESCE(reset_val, 0)
    FROM row_nums
    WHERE rn = 1
  UNION ALL
    SELECT curr.id, curr.group_id, curr.order_val, curr.reset_val, curr.val, curr.rn, 
           COALESCE(curr.reset_val, prev.val + prev.cumsum) 
    FROM row_nums  curr 
      JOIN updated_temp  prev 
        ON  curr.rn-1 = prev.rn 
        AND curr.group_id = prev.group_id
  )
SELECT id, group_id, order_val, reset_val, val, cumsum
FROM updated_temp
ORDER BY group_id, order_val ;
```

Test at [SQLfiddle-2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f3f0ce/2).

---

One more variation, using the older (proprietary) `CONNECT BY` syntax for recursive queries. More compact but I find it more difficult to write and read than the CTE version:

```
WITH row_nums AS
  ( SELECT id, group_id, order_val, reset_val, val, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group_id
                              ORDER BY order_val)
             AS rn,
           COALESCE(reset_val, 0) AS cumsum
    FROM temp
  ) 
SELECT id, group_id, order_val, reset_val, val, rn,  
       COALESCE(reset_val, PRIOR val + PRIOR cumsum, 0) AS cumsum
FROM row_nums
START WITH rn = 1 OR reset_val IS NOT NULL
CONNECT BY  rn-1 = PRIOR rn 
        AND group_id = PRIOR group_id
        AND reset_val IS NULL 
ORDER BY group_id, order_val ;
```

Tested at [SQLfiddle-3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/06b9aa/14).

Comment: Firstly, thank you! Secondly, I must apologize. I neglected a detail. Each group can have multiple resets. I'll revise my question shortly.

Comment: Did you try it? Query works with multiple resets, as it is: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fe988/1 Oops, no it doesn't...

Comment: I did: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3558b9/1/0. I've double checked, but I can't see anything silly I've done to the data. All I did was add 3 rows to the end of group 2, with correct sequence numbers.

Comment: Corrected. Please check as I might have other errors now ;)

Comment: Excellent! Here is a SQLFiddle your query with the updated data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3558b9/4/0. It had just hit me that determining the last reset value was the way to go, but I had never seen the `IGNORE NULLS` syntax. Thank you!

Comment: Also, very clever use of `COUNT`!

Answer (score 4):

As an academic exercise, I've implemented a solution in Postgres.  Now, I know this was a question about Oracle, but it was also framed as a SQL question! :)  If someone is more familiar with Oracle's recursive query syntax, maybe they can find the necessary changes to make this run in Oracle.

## Recursive Querying (in Postgres)

In this solution, I make use of recursive querying, applying the Postgres syntax `WITH RECURSIVE` in my CTE.  The recursive query is as follows:

```
WITH RECURSIVE updated_temp AS (
  SELECT temp.*, 0::numeric AS CUMSUM FROM temp
  UNION
  SELECT curr.id, curr.group_id, curr.order_val, curr.reset_val, curr.val, 
  COALESCE(curr.RESET_VAL,prev.VAL + prev.CUMSUM) AS CUMSUM
  FROM temp AS curr JOIN updated_temp AS prev 
  ON curr.ORDER_VAL-1 = prev.ORDER_VAL AND curr.group_id = prev.group_id)
SELECT id, group_id, order_val, reset_val, val, max(cumsum) FROM updated_temp 
GROUP BY id, group_id, order_val, reset_val, val ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Here is the corresponding [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ed74f/1).

Of course, the key to this query's proper behavior is first using the recursive portion of the query to build your cumulative sum, while making sure to use `COALESCE` to substitute in any `RESET_VAL` which dictates the `CUMSUM` for the row.  The last `SELECT` simply has you filtering for the maximum value of the `CUMSUM` because if the query was built right, the max is identical to the cumulative sum.

## Edit: Oracle version of recursive query

This translation to Oracle was provided by [ypercube](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube):

```
WITH updated_temp (id, group_id, order_val, reset_val, val, cumsum) 
AS (
  SELECT id, group_id, order_val, reset_val, val, 0 
  FROM temp
  UNION ALL
  SELECT curr.id, curr.group_id, curr.order_val, curr.reset_val, curr.val, 
     COALESCE(curr.reset_val, prev.val + prev.cumsum) 
  FROM temp  curr 
    JOIN updated_temp  prev 
      ON  curr.order_val-1 = prev.order_val 
      AND curr.group_id = prev.group_id
)
  SELECT id, group_id, order_val, reset_val, val, max(cumsum) 
  FROM updated_temp 
  GROUP BY id, group_id, order_val, reset_val, val 
  ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Oracle [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3558b9/15)

Comment: Your query, translated into "oracle": http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3558b9/15

Comment: Ha, OK, if I had known those were the only syntax differences, I would've put in the effort to do it in Oracle.  Thanks for the "translation" ypercube!

Comment: Yeah, only minor quirks (no `RECURSIVE`, no `AS` for table aliases, etc.)

Comment: Well, and you don't even need to use `AS` for table aliases, I just do it by compulsion because I like placing a big "`AS`" flag so that when I read my code later I can more quickly parse it.